# Standards compliant code for document.all replacement

Tags: javascript, html, web-standards

We have ancient code that dynamically creates HTML form data from a database, and it was written that references document.all to fetch an array of non-uniquely Id'd check boxes.  I need to find the "method of fewest changes" to get the code to function in a Standards-compliant manner.  My question is about replacing both the `document.myForm` and `document.all` calls with something that produces the same thing, but is standards-compliant.

```
<form name="myForm">
....
    <input name="2630" id="ck_2630" onclick="click(document.myForm.ck_2630[0]);" type="checkbox" value="139"><span onclick="document.myForm.ck_2630[0].checked = !document.myForm.ck_2630[0].checked;click(document.myForm.ck_2630[0]);">Ankle, Left</span><br/>
    <input name="2630" id="ck_2630" onclick="click(document.myForm.ck_2630[1]);" type="checkbox" value="140"><span onclick="document.myForm.ck_2630[1].checked = !document.myForm.ck_2630[1].checked;click(document.myForm.ck_2630[1]);">Ankle, Right</span><br/>
    <input name="2630" id="ck_2630" onclick="click(document.myForm.ck_2630[2]);" type="checkbox" value="141"><span onclick="document.myForm.ck_2630[2].checked = !document.myForm.ck_2630[2].checked;click(document.myForm.ck_2630[2]);">Arm, Left</span><br/>
    <input name="2630" id="ck_2630" onclick="click(document.myForm.ck_2630[3]);" type="checkbox" value="142"><span onclick="document.myForm.ck_2630[3].checked = !document.myForm.ck_2630[3].checked;click(document.myForm.ck_2630[3]);">Arm, Right</span><br/>
...
</form>

<script>
....
function getElem_Opener(strElementName) {
    return document.all(strElementName);
}
....
</script>
```

The code works in all versions of IE, except for IE 11 in Edge mode, because the code uses `document.all('ck_2630')` to fetch the array.  Edge gets rid of document.all (the statement `if (document.all)` returns false), but I don't know if it also does away with the `document.<form name>.<element name/id>` construct, which seems to handle its fields the same way as `document.all` does.

```
<form name="myForm" method="post">
  <button onclick="checkElement('139'); return false;">Select Left Ankle</button><br/>
  <button onclick="checkElement('140'); return false;">Select Right Ankle</button><br/>
  <button onclick="checkElement('141'); return false;">Select Left Arm</button><br/>
  <button onclick="checkElement('142'); return false;">Select Right Arm</button><br/>

  <table name="tbl2630">
    <tr id="rw_2630_139" style="display:none"><td>
      <input name="2630" id="ck_2630" onclick="click(document.myForm.ck_2630[0]);" type="checkbox" value="139"><span onclick="document.myForm.ck_2630[0].checked = !document.myForm.ck_2630[0].checked;click(document.myForm.ck_2630[0]);">Ankle, Left</span>
    </td></tr>
    <tr id="rw_2630_140" style="display:none"><td>
        <input name="2630" id="ck_2630" onclick="click(document.myForm.ck_2630[1]);" type="checkbox" value="140"><span onclick="document.myForm.ck_2630[1].checked = !document.myForm.ck_2630[1].checked;click(document.myForm.ck_2630[1]);">Ankle, Right</span>
        </td></tr>
    <tr id="rw_2630_141" style="display:none"><td>
        <input name="2630" id="ck_2630" onclick="click(document.myForm.ck_2630[2]);" type="checkbox" value="141"><span onclick="document.myForm.ck_2630[2].checked = !document.myForm.ck_2630[2].checked;click(document.myForm.ck_2630[2]);">Arm, Left</span>
    </td></tr>
    <tr id="rw_2630_142" style="display:none"><td>
        <input name="2630" id="ck_2630" onclick="click(document.myForm.ck_2630[3]);" type="checkbox" value="142"><span onclick="document.myForm.ck_2630[3].checked = !document.myForm.ck_2630[3].checked;click(document.myForm.ck_2630[3]);">Arm, Right</span>
    </td></tr>
  </table> 

  <script>
function click(ck) {
    alert("selected item " + ck.name + ", value " + ck.value);
}

function getElem_Opener(strElementName) {
    return document.all(strElementName);
}

function checkElement(intAltID){
  var boolValid = false, boolIsCheckbox = false;
  var strItemID = "2630";
  var elem = getElem_Opener('ck_' + strItemID);
  var elemRow = null, elemUncheck = null, elemTable;

  boolIsCheckbox = true;

  if (elem.length) {                
    for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) { 
      if (elem[i].value == intAltID) {
        elem[i].checked = true;
        boolValid = true;
        elemRow = getElem_Opener('rw_' + strItemID + '_' + intAltID);
        break;                      
        }
      }
    } 

  if (boolValid) {
    if (elemRow != null) {
      elemRow.style.display = 'inline';                 
    }       
  }    
}</script>
</form>
```

Comment: The quoted code doesn't use `document.all` at all. We can't help you with code we cannot see. The full content of your question must be **in** your question, not just linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you. Put a [mcve] **in** the question, ideally using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) to make it runnable. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: The linked jsFiddle does, but it's a different example.  I am working on a fiddle that more closely matches what the code is doing.

Comment: Not a fiddle. **On-site.** Fiddle links are just that: Links.

Comment: oh.  I'll post code once I can confirm it demonstrates the issue.  Sorry for posting the original question prematurely.

Comment: Is your question about `document.all` or `document.myForm`? You can simply replace `document.all(x)` (which was never standard-conforming) with `document.getElementById(x)`. If it's about `document.myForm`, that's standard-conforming.

Comment: I have edited the OP above to include a single small file that demonstrates the issue I'm facing.  Thanks, T.J., for reminding me of the site's requirements for this kind of useful information.  BTW, I cannot see Stack Snippets - do I need to download a separate toolbar for this functionality?

Comment: @Barmar, this is mostly about document.all, but it also is about document.some_form_name, as this site uses both liberally.If Id fields are non-unique, then document.all will return an array (or a node list?  can't keep those straight), but getElementById will only ever return one element (the first one).

Comment: IDs are supposed to be unique. If you're using duplicate IDs, no portable Javascript will by able to deal with it easily.

Comment: You could use `document.getElementByName('2630')` since it looks like your duplicate IDs map to corresponding names.

Comment: This is an error I have to remember often: There is *no* getElementByName, only getElementsByName (pardon the plurality).  That's a part of the reason why we're troubleshooting this: we thought our code was using getElementByName, but it couldn't have been, because it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In all of my research, I have found that the best replacement for `document.all` is `document.getElementById`, unless the outcome is expected to return multiple hits and then you need to use the Name attribute for it, and use `document.getElementsByName`.  This is the solution we've been using, and so far it's worked splendidly.  In places where `document.<formName>` encounters any problems, we've employed the same solution.